# php - find array value that has pattern index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like :

```
$a =['main'=>
[ 
'a' => ['1st'],
'b' => ['2nd'],
'c' => ['3th']
];
```

and I want do like:

```
if(in_array('1st', $a['main'][x])){
...
}
```

I need `x`(now it is `a`) value too

Comment: Does this help :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5592169/3020926 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$resulting_keys = [];
foreach($a['main'] as $key => $value) {
   if(in_array('1st', $value)) {
      $resulting_keys[] = $key;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here are working example:

```
$a = array(

    'main'=> array(

        'a' => '1st',
        'b' => '2nd',
        'c' => '3th'
    )

);


if(in_array('1st', $a['main'])){
     echo 'Yes';
}else{
    echo 'No';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
array_filter($a['main'], function($el) {
    return  in_array('1st', $el);
})
```

Array filter function is a good solution to filter arrays
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php